# Use jQuery .append() inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been trying to call a function that appends html tags inside of pre-existing div tags like this:

```
function loadTextbox(jsonUrl,divId){
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(json) {
    alert('hello');
    $('#' + divId).append('<h2></h2>')
        .find('h').append(json.heading).attr(json.config.backgroundConfig)
        .find('h').attr(json.config.headingConfig).append(json.heading).parent()
        .find('p').attr(json.config.bodyConfig).append(json.body);
    })
}
```

This is a complex example but I haven't been able to get anything working where the append() function is inside any sort of other function. I can append just fine straight from the .js but otherwise no luck. I also know for a fact that the json calls are working as I use an identical call and queries for a different function. Is there a problem with putting append() in a function?

EDIT: Also a note, the above alert does not work as is. However if it is moved one line up (above the $.getJSON call it works fine. Maybe this is important?
Also, I am calling the function directly below it in the same .js file like so:

```
loadTextbox("./json/textbox.json","text");
```

Comment: Short answer: no, there's no problem with calling `append()` in a function. Instead of 'hello', have you tried alerting `$('#'+divId).length` ?

Comment: That alert never calls, actually. If I move the alert to the line above the $.getJSON call and change it like you said it returns "1"

Comment: can you show where are you calling `loadTextbox(jsonUrl,divId)`

Comment: @Yottagray: Try catching `$.ajaxError`. If `$/getJSON` callback won't execute then you may not want to disqualify it just yet (from what I'm reading).

Comment: I love the `alert('hello')`. How very brilliant indeed!

Comment: Brad I believe you are right, the callback is not executing. Any ideas why not?

Comment: @yottagray: If I had to guess, you're trying to access a page that's not on the same domain (most browsers now block cross-domain calls, yet the console will report it received a 200 OK). Try changing it to an `$.ajax` call and bind to the `error` property. You'll be able to see the error thrown (if any) and have more insight in to the solution.

Comment: Try giving full URL e.g. `loadTextbox("http://yourdomain/json/textbox.json","text");`

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: no luck with the full url

Comment: @Brad: Can you be a little more specific with that last comment? An example perhaps? I'm still  a little new to jQuery so you've lost me a bit.

Comment: @Yottagray: Say you're domain is abc.com, but you want data from def.com (or even def.abc.com). Browsers now limit a query to a different domain for security reasons. try this: `$.ajaxError(function(a,b,c){ alert('AJAX Error: ('+b+') '+a.statusText); });`

Comment: @Yott what about ordinary AJAX call to the same URL? Working fine?

Comment: @Wizard: The ordinary AJAX call does work fine.

Comment: Turns out the problem was server-side; the script writing the json file was formatting the document incorrectly. Thanks everybody!

Comment: @Yotta yep that's was going to be my next guess based on your previous comment. BTW @Wizard is not working, if you want it short you can use @Sha (`@` plus first 3 letters) next time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your alert never shows up, when it is inside the function, then that means you're not receiving a response.

If you're using Firefox, use the Firebug plugin to see if an exception is thrown serverside.

Comment: Yes it seems as though the callback is not executing, but Firebug gives me no errors...

Comment: Do you see activity on your server (the target of jsonURL)? Maybe an apache log or a tomcat log or something?

Comment: I'm not seeing any activity at all.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check the docs:

> jQuery.getJSON( url, [ data ], [ success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] )

Which means: your callback is the 3e argument, not the 2nd.

-- edit

So what you want to do is:

```
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, '', function(json) {
  ...
```

Comment: Both `data` and `success` are optional arguments.  If there are only 2 arguments, jQuery will realize that the 2nd is a function and use it as the callback.  This is not the problem.

Comment: You might want to check the docs, their examples show that 2 parameters is correct.

Comment: Yes I have used .getJSON exactly as I did above in several other places in my code to full effect.